# Spring - Access Object In Model With Javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller, model

I'm trying to access a JSON object in my model in my Javascript code. 
It's working when I use inline javascript, but it does not work when import a JS file.

What am I missing?

Controller:

```
String jsonInModel = "{'y':'Jan', 'ty':2000, 'ly':1000}";
model.addAttribute("jsonInModel", jsonInModel);
```

View:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    function printTest(){      
        var test = [[${jsonInModel}]]; //works
    }
</script>
```

Import (bottom):

```
<script src="js/lib/morris-chart/morris-init.js"></script>
```

JS file:

```
$( function () {    
  "use strict";
    var test = [[${jsonInModel}]]; //doens't work
  });
```

I already tried:

```
Defer script:
<script defer="defer" src="js/lib/morris-chart/morris-init.js"></script>

Using CDATA in JS file:
//<![CDATA[
var test = ${jsonInModel}; //doesn't work
//]]>

Beginning JS with:
$(document).ready( function ()
```

Comment: Your controller manages the rendering of the view. Your JS file is not the view, therefore, it does not work. Maybe you think because your JS file is included in your view, it will work, but that's not how it works. That's your browser that downloads and includes scripts to your page, that happens on the client side, and your server has no clue about it.

Comment: @sjahan thanks for the comment! how do I solve it?

Comment: Your best bet if not your only is to try to get the model object as a string on the front-end and with JavaScript you can then convert the string to a javascript object by using JSON.parse. Normally you could add the string value in for example a html element <input type="hidden" value="${jsonInModel}"> like this but that is only one option. Sorry for any syntax errors if there are any.